# How can I debug an oracle stored procedure from a .net web app?

Tags: .net, oracle, debugging, stored-procedures

I have a .net web application that makes heavy use of oracle stored procedures.

One of these is problematic - some times it works, some times it doesn't.

Is there any way to either attach a debugger to oracle when the sp is called, or step into it directly from Visual Studio?

What other debugging techniques are there for a .net/Oracle web app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* step into pl/sql debugging code from visual studio.  (I do it all the time)

You will need to use the Oracle Developer Tools (http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html)  from Oracle but here is their walk-through that should get you up and running.

http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56odp.html

it takes a little set up, but once it is working you can debug directly from .net into Oracle code.

Here is Christian Shay's walk-through (he's the Product Manager in the .NET and Windows group at Oracle)
http://cshay.blogspot.com/2006/07/plsql-debugger-in-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your stored procedures with Pl\Sql Developer. That's what i do. :)

I don't think you'll be able to debug the Oracle SP from the .net code (or at least im not familiar with the technique).

And by the way, If you have a lot of code logic in your stored procedures, then maybe you should think about moving it out to your code base (At least if speed isn't a very crucial aspect in your application).

Answer (score 0):

You can't step into pl/sql code from visual studio using debugger. If you need to debug the stored procedure you must have access to its body and you can use [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html?gclid=CJSUzJDYiaMCFVAj3wodDBdDbg) for that. Of course there is [technique with using DBMS_DEBUG](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/debug.html), but I think with PL/SQL Developer will be much easier, it looks like this :
[image]

Comment: Oracle's free SQL Developer has the debugger too.

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html